# how auto scrolling when to selected UItextfield then click on return to change position in view?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

//this code for autoscrolling when select UItextfield.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y - 10);
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y - textField.frame.origin.y);
}
```

Comment: if you are looking for manage Keyboard while textfiled editing check this: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager just add its class and write one line in appdelegaete method thats it

Comment: func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y - 10)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y - textField.frame.origin.x)
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textField` delegate method `textFieldShouldReturn` and consider below example:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    //set setContentOffset here
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

to scroll the view when a textfield is pressed (keyboard is up) you have to add a `NSNotificationCenter` observer on the keyboard state.
simply add this 2 lines in `viewDidLoad()`

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

then add the functions to change the `self.view.frame.origin.y`accordingly.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
    }
}
```